# JQuery/ How to show alerts for each table cell?

Tags: javascript, jquery

This is my HTML table.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("button").click(function() {
    $("tr").each(
      $("td").each(
        function() {
          alert($(this).text());
        }
      );

    );
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button>Alert the value of each list item</button>

<table>
  <thead>
    <th>
      h1
    </th>
    <th>
      h2
    </th>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>a1</td>
      <td>b1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>a2</td>
      <td>b2</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

In browser it looks like this.

[image]

When I click on the button I want one alert for each table cell value.

For example from the above there are 4 cells (2 cells per row).

So I want four alerts like "a1", "b1", "a2" and "b2"

As shown above I am trying with `.each` function of jquery but still no luck :(

Can someone take a look and let me know as to how do this with jquery ?

Comment: you are missing the function in your first `each`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't need double loop.Single loop works for it.

```js
  
  $("button").click(function() {
   $('tr td').each(function (index, element) {
    alert($(this).text())
 });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button>Alert the value of each list item</button>

<table>
  <thead>
    <th>
      h1
    </th>
    <th>
      h2
    </th>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>a1</td>
      <td>b1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>a2</td>
      <td>b2</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can just loop over the `td` on the table like this:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("button").click(function() {
    $("td").each(function() {
      alert($(this).text());
    });
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button>Alert the value of each list item</button>

<table>
  <thead>
    <th>
      h1
    </th>
    <th>
      h2
    </th>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>a1</td>
      <td>b1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>a2</td>
      <td>b2</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

1. You can just use `$("tr td")` selector to loop on all 4 td

```js
$('button').click(function() {
  $("tr td").each(function() {

    alert($(this).text());
  })
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button>Alert the value of each list item</button>

<table>
  <thead>
    <th>
      h1
    </th>
    <th>
      h2
    </th>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>a1</td>
      <td>b1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>a2</td>
      <td>b2</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

Like this?

```js
    $(document).ready(function() {
      $("button").click(function() {
      var ele =  $("td");
       $.each(ele,
            function() {
              alert($(this).text());
            }
          );
      });
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button>Alert the value of each list item</button>

    <table>
      <thead>
        <th>h1</th>
        <th>h2 </th>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td>a1</td>
          <td>b1</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>a2</td>
          <td>b2</td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
```